# Create a function to list array of values in an object

Tags: arrays, object, key

This is for an assignment. Please DO NOT down vote. Everybody had to start somewhere, and each person learns differently.

I need to create a function that builds an array consisting solely of the values in any given simpler object: for example:
//headache {abd:123, def: 345, ghi: 756} should yield array juice [123, 345, 756];

If I type the object.key 'headache.abd', the console will show the value '123', and using this logic, I attempted to use the 'array.push' function to build a list. Here's my code:

```js
function listAllValues(headache) {
  var juice =[];
  for (var keys in headache){
      juice.push(obj.keys);
  }
  console.log(juice);
}
```

//But the above code prints out [undefined, undefined, undefined], instead of [123, 345, 756]. Where did I mess up? I feel like I'm close, but I've been unsuccessfully trying various combinations :(, help please.

Comment: where is headache.post complete code

Comment: headache is a basic object, I believe I posted it in the opening of the question:// headache {abd:123, def: 345, ghi: 756}

Comment: So, you're just trying to add the keys of an object to a list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: Although, you should check the object itself first, since I wouldn't expect it to yield undefineds. I suspect the object you're passing in to the function isn't what you think it is.

Comment: This code doesn't even run. `obj` isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

use headache[keys] insteda of obj.keys.

```js
function listAllValues(headache) {
  var juice =[];
  for (var keys in headache){
      juice.push(headache[keys]);
  }
  alert(juice);
}


headache = {abd:123, def: 345, ghi: 756} ;
listAllValues(headache);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple wonky things:

- It tries to use a `obj` object, but that doesn't exist
- You're never using the `keys` item that the loop gives you

  - It should probably be `key` instead
- You're never filtering it using `hasOwnProperty` which you should always do.
- You're printing inside the function which is generally regarded as bad

Fixed up code:

```
function listAllValues(headache) {
  var juice =[];
  for (var key in headache){
        if (headache.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          juice.push(headache[key]);
       } 
  }
  return juice;
}

console.log(listAllValues({abd:123, def: 345, ghi: 756} ))
```